# CSS selection query for just parent content

Tags: html, css

Say I have the following.

```
   <div class="price">$64 used
    <span class="originally">$160 new</span>
    <span class="you-save">You save 60%</span>
   </div>
```

I only want to select the "$64 used", not the rest in the child spans. How would I do something like this? I have tried selecting like below and none work.

```
article > .price
article > .price:not(span)
article > div:not(span)
article > div:not(.originally):not(.you-save)
```

EDIT: For clarification..

```
const test = document.querySelector('section > div.price');
console.log(test.innerText);
```

$64 Used$160 New
You save 60%

I only want $64 Used. Is this even possible? I did not make the site, I am trying to scrape this.

Comment: You style `article > .price` one way, and then overwrite that styling via `article > .price span`. Eg. set color to red on `.price` and color back to black on `.price span`. It would help if you could explain what your use case is, eg if you're trying to use a CSS selector for a JQuery selector something, or just for styling.

Comment: `div:not(span)` doesn't make sense... select divs that are not spans?

Answer (score 0):

```
div.price
```

do the work. For me, better is just use

```
.price.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a small change:

```
<div class="price">
  <span>$64 used</span>
  <span class="originally">$160 new</span>
  <span class="you-save">You save 60%</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
article > .price > span:not([class]) { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how `tag:not()` works. You can exclude a `span` tag from taking the style for `span` tags. But you can not select children this way.

Just apply a style to the `div` and overwride the properties for the children.

```css
.price {
  color: blue;
}

span.originally {
  color: green;
}

span.you-save {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="price">$64 used
    <span class="originally">$160 new</span>
    <span class="you-save">You save 60%</span>
   </div>
</article>
```